# React Routing Trouble, url updates but comonent doesnt render,nested routing

Tags: reactjs

I've got this app that contains another 3 apps,

I'm trying to link from withing the nested app to other components that belong specifically to that app,
however I'm getting some strange behavior, 
The List loads, The EmailDetails component doesn't.

The URL itself also changes, but i just get a blank page

i also get this in the console:

React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead

The Main App Routing:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
            <NavBar ></NavBar>
        <Switch>
          <div className="wrapper">
            <Route exact  path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact component={Overview} path="/app" />
            <Route exact component={EmailApp} path="/email" />
            <Route exact component={ToDoApp} path="/todo" />
            <Route exact component={BookApp} path="/book" />
            <footer>Footer</footer>
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The Nested Email App Routing:

```
  render() {
    const {emails}=this.state
    const location=this.props.location.pathname
    const emailList=  (location==='/email')? <EmailList emails={emails}></EmailList>:''
    return (

      <div className="email-wrapper">
        <Filter onSetFilter={ this.onSetFilter } placeHolder='Search By Sender,subject,Id'></Filter>
       {emailList}
        <Router>
          <Switch>
        <Route  exact component={EmailDetails}  path="/email/:emailId/" />
        </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

The Link Comes From a different component and looks like this :

```
<Link  to={`/email/${email.id}`}>
```

Comment: why are you using <Router> inside email component? See https://codepen.io/pshrmn/pen/YZXZqM on how to do nested routing.

Comment: becuase i dont want to stack my main app page with routes, is that a bad practice?

Comment: Ofcourse it's okay to not stack the main app with routes. My question is why wrap it inside <Router> component again? Using <Switch> directly without <Router> should be fine

Comment: i tried doing that too mate, it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: is it giving same error?

Comment: no, blank page with nothing in it , i got a hello world in that component, and still got that console error

Comment: Can you try wrapping the switch with <React.Fragment> instead of the <Router> ?

Comment: tried, same result